# How to make python3 import examine .so and ...-g.so as well?

Tags: python, boost-python

We expose C++ code to python via boost.python. We produce release and debug builds.

release builds produce lib.so files

debug builds produce lib-g.so files.

Our python code then

```
import lib<mymodule>
```

Is there a way to place a hook such that those import statements can explore both libmymodule.so and if not found libmymodule-g.so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
import importlib

try:
    import libmymudule
except ImportError:
    libmymudule = importlib.import_module("libmymudule-g")
```